Creating a listener for Branch.io deferred deep link in .NET MAUI
I'm trying to implement deferred deep linking in my .NET MAUI app. The documentation for .NET MAUI on Branch's website is a bit thin and wanted to see if anyone else has already tackled this.
First, creating deep links section of the documentation mentions a callback but doesn't get into it. I assume the callback is the function that will actually handle reading any data that comes with the deep link once the user installs/opens the mobile app but I'm not sure if this is actually what they mean by callback.
The documentation also mentions using a listener as stated below:

Please note that Branch recommends receiving data from the listener to
prevent a race condition.

Has anyone done this before? If so, I'd appreciate some pointers. Here's my current thinking on how to handle this:

Create a page where all deep links point to e.g. DeepLinkHandlerPage.xaml. This is the page that will understand what the deep link is telling us.
Once the user installs/opens the app and hits this page, we can collect all the parameters we received from the deep link and decide what to do next. For example, the deep link maybe pointing to a particular article or product, in which case, we can send the user to the appropriate page and pull up the necessary product/article data.

Or am I missing the "listener" concept all together here?
I'd love to see a code sample to better understand some of these concepts and how they're implemented. I'd appreciate any suggestions/pointers. Thanks!
